# how to handle bugfix in a phundament composer package

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, composer-php, phundament

i want to fix a bug in twitter bootstrap composer package used by Phundament3 0.15.0. How can i do this without changing code in the vendor folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork the package and require your fork in composer. See [docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) for details.

Comment: See also the [Phundament Wiki](https://github.com/phundament/app/wiki/Packages)...